# Spring Boot java: Process/Compare lines of very large file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, bigdata

I have this app where i process a very large file, Extract the lines that have the same first 5 characters (i call this currentlineId ), use them to create an object and do something with it, example sample of the file contents:

```
AZDFS12345678998765432345678
AZDFS09876545432345678987654
AZDFS34568987654567890987654
AZDFS12345670987654345678998
AZDFS12345098734567765123456
// the lines above have the same first 5 characters, they create Object1.


FGHJUY121324
FGHJUY089909
FGHJUYTTUTUU
//same for the lines above, they create Object2.
```

NB: the lines will always be in an order where lines with the same first 5 will always be together (abover/below each other) so i wonn't have lines all over the place

My current function code:

```
 private void processScpFile(File file) {
        LOGGER.info("Processing File: {} ", file.getName());

        try (var br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

            String currentLine;
            String lastLineId = null;
            List<String> similarLineIdsList = new ArrayList<>();

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (StringUtils.isEmpty(lastLineId)) {
                    lastLineId = currentLine.substring(0,5);
                }

                if (lastLineId.equals(currentLine.substring(0,5))) {
                    similarLineIdsList.add(currentLine);
                }

                else if (!lastLineId.equals(currentLine.substring(0,5))) {


                    doSomethinsWithTheList(similarLineIdsList);

                    similarLineIdsList.clear();

                    similarLineIdsList.add(currentLine);
                    lastLineId= currentLine.substring(0,5);
                }
            }

            doSomethinsWithTheList(similarLineIdsList);

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Couldn't read file, {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Now this has worked well up until now, but going forward i have to process files where i would have for instance over 100k lines with same first 5, which makes this process very slow.
Please do you have any suggestion on haow to make this process faster, thank you

Edit: just to be precise it's the generating the list with the same first 5 chars that's slower as the number of similar lines gets larger.

Comment: Profile your code to find out which part is slow. For instance, is it still slow if you don't call `doSomethinsWithTheList`? If it isn't , optimise that.

Comment: fundamentally, this is a good scenario for using multiple threads and/or multiple processes. If that doesn't get you there, you can think about using multiple machines (i.e. Hadoop) https://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: @tgdavies doSomethinsWithTheList is just a function that i call, it's the generating list part that's slow, as it checks over 100K lines per object

Comment: If you simply read through the file, and don't do anything at all with the lines, is performance ok?

Comment: yes i think it's the constant lines comparing that's causing slowness

Comment: So if you do the comparisons, but don't add the lines to the list, then performance is bad. If you remove the comparisons, and do nothing with the lines, it's OK?

Comment: `substring` creates a new object, so if you use `startsWith` and only use `substring` when the prefix changes that may help.